# File specific visudo permissions

Tags: apache-2.4, bash, sudo

I'm trying to integrate some bash scripts into a website admin area.

## Background

I'm running apache on Ubuntu server. Giving apache (www-data) sudo rights is far from ideal, so I'm not going to. However, it is possible to specify sudo access for non sudo users.

For a number of security reasons apache must have none, or at worst, severely limited sudo access...  So, a suitable work around is to specify the specific scripts that www-data can sudo.

In order to control this, I've created and edited `etc/sudoers.tmp` using `visudo`.

I have added a test script in `var/www/html/scripts` called `sudoscripts.sh`.

This is simply:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo whoami
```

So, as a test, I added the line:

`www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

This works as expected. However, this enables access to all scripts, anywhere.

## Question

I then replaced this with:

`www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /var/www/html/scripts/sudoscript.sh`

This fails giving the error (within my application exception):

`sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`

... i.e: no sudo access.

Can anyone point out what I've done wrong? I've had a look at a few examples/other stack overflow threads and they are either a poor match, or unanswered.

## edit for clarity

Here is the full file:

```
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        exempt_group=sudo
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d

# Apache using /var/www/html/scripts

# (doesnt work)
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /var/www/html/scripts/sudoscript.sh

# (works)
# www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that you are not running the command you entered into the sudoers file with sudo.

You are running `/var/www/html/scripts/sudoscript.sh` directly from your webserver. The script then calls sudo with `whoami`, but `whoami` is not allowed in your sudoers file. You would need to set `whoami` in sudoers, instead of the script location.

This doesn't make much sense of course.

What would make more sense would be:

*/var/www/html/scripts/sudoscript.sh*

```
#!/bin/sh
whoami
```

*/etc/sudoers*

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /var/www/html/scripts/sudoscript.sh
```

And then run the script with sudo from your webserver:

```
sudo /var/www/html/scripts/sudoscript.sh
```

Comment: That gives: `sudo: a password is required`.

Comment: Nice one! That has solved it.

Answer (score 1):

comment out requiretty in visudo or put ! in front of it like:

Defaults !requiretty

Comment: There is no `Defaults requiretty` line.

Comment: So try to add it: Defaults !requiretty

Comment: Note that this will set the option for ALL users.

Comment: I don't want to change the permissions of all users or all files- I want passwordless sudo access by www-data of only one file.